# Aggregating column based on datetime column of another table PySpark/SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm currently attempting to perform a date-dependent aggregation on a table's column using dates from another table. Table 1 contains user IDs and dates (plus other information to not be aggregated). Table 2 contains the values I wish to aggregate along with the same IDs and distinct dates.

The goal is to aggregate values from table 2 *only* if they precede the date on a row in table 1.

In the illustration below, the aggregation function desired is "mean", however if a general PySpark (or SQL) solution could be provided that allows this aggregation function to be either a built in (F.mean, F.sum) *or* custom user-defined function, that would be ideal.

**Table 1** - Date table (note: user IDs can be repeated in both tables)

```
+---+---------- +----------          
|USER|   DATE   |USER_STATE|   
+---+---------- +---------- 
|  3 | 7/1/2019 |  Current |
|  1 | 6/9/2019 |  Expired |
|  1 | 1/1/2019 |  Current |
+----+----------+-----------
```

**Table 2** - Aggregation table

```
+---+---------- +----------          
|USER|CHARGEDATE|AMOUNTPAID|   
+---+---------- +---------- 
|  1 | 7/1/2018 |  10.00   |
|  1 | 5/1/2019 |  40.00   |
|  1 | 2/2/2019 |  10.00   |
|  3 | 1/2/2019 |  15.00   |
+----+----------+-----------
```

**Desired Output** - aggregation (mean) is calculated per user and is dependent on CHARGEDATE being prior to DATE in table 1

```
+---+---------- +----------+---------------          
|USER|   DATE   |USER_STATE|MEAN_AMOUNTPAID|   
+---+---------- +----------+--------------- 
|  3 | 7/1/2019 |  Current |    15.00      |
|  1 | 6/9/2019 |  Expired |    20.00      | 
|  1 | 1/1/2019 |  Current |    10.00      |
+----+----------+----------+--------------- 
Row 2 - includes all user 1 Table 2 values because all ChargedDate< date 
Row 3 - includes only includes user 1's row 1 Table 2 value because it's the only chargeddate less than date
```

I'm aware this could inefficiently be accomplished by running a loop on each row in Table 1, getting the DATE for that row, and using it to query the second table. I'm looking for a solution without loops if possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`PySpark`** way to do this would involve converting your **`DATE`** and **`CHARGEDATE`** columns to **`DateType`** to able to **`filter`** on **`DATE>CHARGEDATE`**. So I assumed your date was in format **`"M/d/yyyy"`**, if it was other way around just replace that to **`"d/M/yyyy"`**

```
#data.show()
#+----+--------+----------+
#|USER|    DATE|USER_STATE|
#+----+--------+----------+
#|   3|7/1/2019|   Current|
#|   1|6/9/2019|   Expired|
#|   1|1/1/2019|   Current|
#+----+--------+----------+

#aggregation.show()
#+----+----------+----------+
#|USER|CHARGEDATE|AMOUNTPAID|
#+----+----------+----------+
#|   1|  7/1/2018|      10.0|
#|   1|  5/1/2019|      40.0|
#|   1|  2/2/2019|      10.0|
#|   3|  1/2/2019|      15.0|
#+----+----------+----------+

from pyspark.sql import functions as F
data.join(aggregation,['USER'])\
      .withColumn("DATE",F.to_date("DATE","M/d/yyyy"))\
      .withColumn("CHARGEDATE", F.to_date("CHARGEDATE", "M/d/yyyy"))\
      .filter("DATE>CHARGEDATE")\
      .groupBy("USER","DATE","USER_STATE").agg(F.mean("AMOUNTPAID").alias("mean_amount_paid"))\
      .show()

+----+----------+----------+----------------+
|USER|      DATE|USER_STATE|mean_amount_paid|
+----+----------+----------+----------------+
|   1|2019-06-09|   Expired|            20.0|
|   1|2019-01-01|   Current|            10.0|
|   3|2019-07-01|   Current|            15.0|
+----+----------+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to removing the ".filter"  and specifying it as a second join condition? It seems to produce similar results. As an exmple, with assuming the date columns are already date format, below:


`conditions=[data.USER==aggregation.USER, data.DATE>aggregation.CHARGEDATE] `
`data.join(aggregation, conditions)`

Comment: Yes they will both produce same result and that’s a good question because I wasn’t sure either about which would be more performant. My reasoning was making the join a little more complex would be less performant than a filter . I could b wrong because I haven’t benchmarked the two. But I’m almost positive that the difference won’t be that huge

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and also check it out here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11cf8/6)

```
select
  d.users,
  date,
  user_state,
  avg(amount) as mean_amount_paid
from data d
join aggregation a
on d.users = a.users
where d.date > a.ch_date
group by
  d.users,
  date,
  user_state
```

Output:

```
|users | date | user_state | mean
+-------------------------------+
  1  2019-01-01  Current      10
  1  2019-06-09  Expired      20
  3  2019-07-01  Current      15
+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks.I'm hoping to use a similar logic to run a custom aggregation function (not just those supported out-of-the-box by SQL). Do you have any idea how to accomplish this? Perhaps using PySpark?

Comment: could u elaborate on the custom aggregation function? if spark inbuilt aggs are not adequate then u would have to use pands udaf

Comment: @MohammadMurtazaHashmi Yes, I was referring to a Pandas UDF. However, if you are able to show me the equivalent Pyspark code that does the same thing as the above SQL code posted by Zealous (using Spark builtin mean agg), I would be able to substitute the pandas agg function. I'm having trouble converting the SQL logic to Pyspark.